# Is it more efficient to have a external CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, performance

In every website that I have programmed I have used a external CSS stylesheet to style text and whatnot because it is much easier to manage. I have included this script into my head tag like this:

```
<link href = "cssscript.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

However, I also see people write there HTML code and CSS all into one script by adding all their CSS code into a `<style>` tag just below the head tag. I was wondering if there were any differences in efficiency and speed by using one method or the other. Does using an external stylesheet change the loading time of the website in any way?

Comment: First, css files aren't script but stylesheet.

Comment: @NirvikBaruah [Tips for authoring fast-loading HTML pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Tips_for_authoring_fast-loading_HTML_pages)

Comment: This certainly seems like a question that can be answered based on fact, not opinion. I don't see why it was closed for the given reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The main advantage** is that your browser will ***cache*** your CSS file and therefore your website pages will load faster. Using separate CSS files is also better because you can have your whole CSS code in a separate file and this helps focusing properly on your work.

Comment: I think what you might have meant to say here is 'using external CSS files'. Separate CSS files could be mis-construed as (multiple) CSS files (eg. SASS)

Answer (score 3):

**If your styles are short and not re-used, it's better to use internal CSS, but if your CSS is long, it's better to use external CSS.**

Please see this link: http://infoheap.com/internal-vs-external-css/

> **Comparison of external and internal CSS**
>
> Here are a few things you may want to consider before deciding if a CSS chunk should go in an external or internal file:
>
> **CSS caching**
>
> External CSS is cached (assuming you are using right http expire headers). However, it uses some of the cache space of the browser. It's not a very big concern, but is something worth keeping in mind with mobile devices becoming more prominent.
>
> If you have many repeat activities by the same user, you get many benefits from external CSS file caching. With CSS caching, the stylesheet is saved, or cached. When a user loads a page from the website, the stylesheet only has to load for the first (and not subsequent) pages.
>
> **DNS lookup and an extra round trip**
>
> An external cache causes an extra roundtrip and potentially one extra DNS lookup. This causes some latency at the user's end.
>
> **CSS fetching and page rendering**
>
> The page rendering is blocked until all external CSS files have been fetched. Too many external CSS files slow down the page render speed.
>
> **My recommendation**
>
> If you don't have many repeat visits by the same users, it's a good idea to avoid too many external CSS files. When using minimal amounts of CSS, it's best to put them in the document internally.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the benefits above, it is also nice to have one location for the css. Imagine you have a large website with many pages which all uses the same css. If you have to alter the css you can do this in the external css file and all pages will be affected. Otherwise you must change the css in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter, but as your webpages get larger and more complex, you will want to separate the two pages for readability and presentation. It will greatly reduce the size of the HTML file, and will create a nice looking easy editable CSS file. In fact, a separate file will be slower, as the browser needs to fetch an extra file, but the time difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

It would be technically faster to load one big file than execute multiple requests to the server to load scripts/css. But if your script is required on multiple page, you might gain in speed that the scripts and stylesheets get cached while your html pages might not.

In other words, if you had styles and scripts inside `<script> and <style>` tags. You'd have to redownload them multiple times if html pages aren't cached.

If they are external links, the first load will take some time but the following page loads will be fast as css and scripts won't be downloaded again.